# Need apache camel jars for 2.13.1 camel version

Tags: jar, apache-camel

Can anyone provide me the jar's for apache camel 2.13.1 version.

I need the following jars..

```
org.apache.camel:camel-http4:jar:2.13.1, 
org.apache.camel:camel-jms:jar:2.13.1, 
org.apache.camel:camel-cache:jar:2.13.1, 
org.apache.camel:camel-tagsoup:jar:2.13.1,
org.apache.camel:camel-test:2.13.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest Apache Camel release is 2.12.2, which you can see from the official Apache website
http://camel.apache.org/download.html

You can find all the Apache Camel releases in the ASF archive at
http://archive.apache.org/dist/camel/apache-camel/

There is no Apache Camel 2.13.1 or 2.13.0 release yet.
Apache Camel 2.13.0 is currently *in development* and not released yet.

I assume the version number you got is wrong. But you can download Camel from its official website.

Also JARs can be downloaded from Maven Central.

Comment: Hi claus thanks for the quick reply. I have seen in the maven repo, also  but the jars are available till 2.12.2 version.

Comment: Yes because that is the latest release. There is NO Camel 2.13.1 release.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are looking for some feature/fix rolls with 2.13.1 and you might have followed Camel Jira.

If you are looking for a specific fix, you can find the status/possible patch in jira.

example: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7092

or you could take help of people :-)